# How to Array Set in TableView With SectionHeaderTitle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

> This is my array and i set in TableView with Section Wise.this array is Dynamically so that value is Increase or decrease.
>
> Set Date in Header Section Title
>
> Same date value is included in One Section.

**So What is the Method of TableView that i set data in table with Section wise.**

```
({
    date = "2016-07-09 06:46:00 +0000";
    heartrate = 89;
},
    {
    date = "2016-07-07 06:46:00 +0000";
    heartrate = 88;
},
    {
    date = "2016-07-06 06:46:00 +0000";
    heartrate = 90;
},
    {
    date = "2016-07-09 06:46:00 +0000";
    heartrate = 102;
},
    {
    date = "2016-07-07 06:46:00 +0000";
    heartrate = 98;
},
    {
    date = "2016-07-07 06:46:00 +0000";
    heartrate = 97;
})
```

> Here I set Image and I want to set like this with section wise row set.

[image]

Comment: post some code what you have tried?

Comment: check my below answer.Hope this will solve your problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do as follow(Hope this will solve your problem)-

1- Take a global `NSMutableArray` i.e. **resultArray**;

2- Add these lines of code where you make your array (also work with **dynamic array size**)-

```
resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];

NSArray *groupsDate = [yourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.date"];
   // for sorted array- [[yourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.date"]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

for (NSString *groupDateValue in groupsDate)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [newDict setObject:groupDateValue forKey:@"date"];

    NSArray *groupRate = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date = %@", groupDateValue]];

    [newDict setObject:groupRate forKey:@"heartrate"];

    [resultArray addObject:newDict];
}

NSLog(@"result %@",resultArray);
```

now add `tableView` `dataSource/Delegate` methods-

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return resultArray.count;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSArray *rowC=[[resultArray objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:@"heartrate"];

    return rowC.count;

}
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 0, tableView.frame.size.width/2-5, 30)];

    [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16]];

    [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [label1 setText:[self getDateFromString:[[resultArray valueForKey:@"date"]objectAtIndex:section]]];

    [label1 setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

    [view addSubview:label1];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    return view;

}

-(NSString *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",string];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"];
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];

    return stringFromDate;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

        cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Heart Rate = %@",[[[[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"heartrate"] valueForKey:@"heartrate"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"heartrate"] valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"date=%@ and heartRate= %@",[[[[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"heartrate"] valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[[[[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]valueForKey:@"heartrate"] valueForKey:@"heartrate"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

this is the output screen-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) First you have to create one array for your section titles which contains unique value. You can do unique your values by comparing value with each other inside array.

2) Second thing you have to create second array which contains dictionaries for your sections. Like section 1 has 2 rows

3) Then you have to implement tableview datasource methods.

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: // required method

– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: // required method

– numberOfSectionsInTableView:

– tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
```

Comment: Yes you right but How to Section wise data save in tableview ?

Comment: Create one array, which contains your sections data. It stores section name as key and value contains array means your section data.

Comment: refere this link for how to create data structure : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

Comment: Here I have created demo for you using static array data structure. Hope you get idea. https://www.sendspace.com/file/jdga6j

Comment: @sanandiyavipul Have you checked the demo?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already added data to row in table view.

Use the following functions for section view.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{}
```

These are by default functions for showing section in table view. Fetch the Date key(according to your data structure) and add it as title in section view and the heart rate to the row in section. If you don't understand this please let me know I'll modify my answer accordingly :)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes you right but How to Section wise data save in tableview ?

Comment: @sanandiyavipul i am not getting you. can you explain in detail or post some examples with your code so that we can give you accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate the both data i array by using this:

```
for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++){
 NSDictionary *dic=array[i];
[dateArray addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"date"]]; //date array is mutable array
[heartRateArray addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"heartrate"]]; //mutable array
}
```

by this you can differentiate both date and heart rate and use the table view delegate and datasource.